# sum is 1 irrespective of numbers

Tags: c++, function, sum

having cal_sum in the last cout statement gives 1 as output irrespective of the values entered. when x+y is entered in place of cal_sum in cout statement then I m getting the correct answer .why?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 //sum of 2 numbers.
 int cal_sum(int a,int b)
 {
     int sum;
     sum=a+b;
     return sum;
 }
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    cout<<"enetr any 2 no\n";
    cin>>x;
    cin>>y;
    cal_sum(x,y);
    cout<<"sum ="<<cal_sum;
}
```

Comment: When you call `cal_sum`, its returned value needs to be stored somewhere, e.g. in a new variable. `int result = cal_sum(x, y)`. Then you can use `result` as your variable in `cout <<"sum = " << result;`

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `cal_sum(x,y); cout<<"sum ="<<cal_sum;` should be `cout<<"sum ="<<cal_sum(x, y);`

Comment: Set a high compiler warning level. I get `../main.cpp:17:20: warning: the address of 'int cal_sum(int, int)' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]` with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing `cal_sum` itself, when you should be printing `cal_sum(x, y)`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

//sum of 2 numbers.
int cal_sum(int a,int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int x,y;
    std::cout << "enetr any 2 no\n";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cout << "sum =" << cal_sum(x,y);
}
```

You might be wondering why printing `cal_sum` always prints `1`. The reason is that there is no overload for the `<<` operator which takes a function, so instead `cal_sum` is printed as a `bool`. `cal_sum` is not a `nullptr`, so it is `true` or `1` as shown in the output.

Comment: fwiw, there are overloads that take function pointers as parameters

Comment: @idclev463035818 are you sure? I could [only find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) overloads for function pointers taking `std::basic_ostream` as a parameter. Also for `void*` but that is not compatible with function pointers. The compiler will also warn you about pointer to bool conversion with OP's code.

Comment: yes it is function pointers of specific type, but you wrote "there is no overload ... which takes a function"